# What does Islam say about renting rooms at a higher price than the owner?

Tags: halal-haram, business, rent

We're a group of students, studying at a prestigious University, we had to shift from city campus to its permanent campus due to some new Govt. policies. Currently we're living in a rural area and have been facing various problems, but the main issue abou which I am going to request you to clarify me is that, over here two students have made such an accommodation crisis that if you need a room for living you have to take the room from them with double and sometimes tripled rent price than if you were able to take it directly from the owner of the building. For example, a room would cost 1500 bucks per month if you take it from the owner, but now you have to spend 4000 bucks (more or less) for that room monthly only because of those two students, as they have already taken those room and left us with no choice but to take rooms with that high price from them. And due to lack of adequate apartments, we have no alternatives to stay in other places or buildings as they have taken all of them and making a lot of money out of it. And we are the victims of their business.

Now my question is, what they are doing, according to the rulings of islam, is it halal or haram business?

Comment: What about contacting the owner(s) directly?

Comment: These apartments were almost vacant back then cz a very few residents live here, now he is getting comparatively more money than before without doing anything, just by relying on those students who convinced him that he will be getting money every month without longing for boarders, they will do it for him. That's why he will not take this into consideration. But my question was, the way they are making money is that haram or halal?

Comment: So I take it that these 2 students rent rooms from only one owner who is happy with long-term contracts so that he does not have to bother about who actually lives there? I'm a westener, and can't give an answer based on Islam. What I guess is that this would be alright it they charged only a few percent as a kind of commission, but is gouging at that rate like you describe it.

Comment: And for a better understanding, do they do any work like a janitor? Like if heating fails or the toilet doesn't flush?

Comment: Nah, they are some absolute manipulators, they can make you think zero is equals to 1 while they talk to you and they promise in the very moment you ask them to fix something of the apartment and leave you exactly in the same situation as you were before, by this you fed up and learn to adjust, and forget about the inconveniences you're up to. This is the case here going on.

Comment: So even if they only *promise* to fix something, they have the *role* of a janitor, probably telling lies to the owner. Contact the real owner and hear his story of the things. I guess he would really be displeased if something that doesn't get fixed will put a danger to his property, like a leaking pipe or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subleasing at a higher rent than one is paying to the owner is permissible according to the majority (Maliki, Shafi'i and Hanbali madhab). Lease is the sale of the usufruct of some property for a period of time and by default that includes the right to benefit from it by giving it on a lease. It is a type of trade and the very point of trade is to make a profit by selling something at a higher price than what it cost you.

However, according to the Hanafis and one opinion of the Hanablis subleasing at a higher rent is only permissible if the lessor adds something to it (such as painting or adding furniture to a building). While the Hanafis also permit it if the genus of the two rents is different.

**Ref:** https://islamqa.info/en/answers/82568/ , https://islamqa.org/hanafi/darulfiqh/156557/is-it-permissible-to-sublease/

> ذهب المالكية والشافعية إلى جواز ذلك مطلقا، أي سواء أكانت الأجرة الثانية مساوية أم زائدة أم ناقصة؛ لأن الإجارة بيع كما تقدم، فله أن يبيعها بمثل الثمن، أو بزيادة أو بنقص كالبيع، ووافقهم أحمد في أصح الأقوال عنده
>
> وذهب الحنفية إلى جواز الإجارة الثانية إن لم تكن الأجرة فيها من جنس الأجرة الأولى، للمعنى السابق، أما إن اتحد جنس الأجرتين فإن الزيادة لا تطيب للمستأجر. وعليه أن يتصدق، وصحت الإجارة الثانية لأن الفضل فيه شبهة. أما إن أحدث زيادة في العين المستأجرة فتطيب الزيادة لأنها في مقابلة الزيادة المستحدثة.وذهب الحنابلة في قول ثان لهم إلى أنه إن أحدث المستأجر الأول زيادة في العين جاز له الزيادة في الأجر دون اشتراط اتحاد جنس الأجر أو اختلافه، وسواء أذن له المؤجر أو لم يأذن.
>
> <sup>— [Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/455#p1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Although making a high profit in business is not prohibited in Islam, it is discouraged.
Allah will deal with people like themselves when they face problems in this world and also on Judgment Day.

> The Prophet (S) replied: “Verily, God will only show mercy to those of
> His servants who show mercy to others.

[Reference](https://www.al-islam.org/message-thaqalayn/vol-10-n-3-autumn-2009/pearls-wisdom-selection-hadiths-prophet-muhammad/pearls)